# redirect to requested page after login using spring

Tags: spring, security, redirect, authentication

This is my spring-security.xml

```
    <http auto-config="true" path-type="ant">
    <intercept-url pattern="/myaccount.html*" access="ROLE_CUSTOMER"/>       
    <intercept-url pattern="/viewpage.html*" access="ROLE_CUSTOMER"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login.html"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="ssoAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                login-processing-url="/j_security_check" default-target-url="/login.html"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="ssoLogoutHandler" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,loggedIn,_bt,slc_f,slc_t,_px_i,attempt_auto_login"/>
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none"/>
</http>
```

If user access some URL I want to intercept him to login. After it needs to be redirected to the original requested page by user.

Above xml helps me to intercept when user access viewpage.html but after login success it is not taking me to viewpage.html. Instead it takes me to myaccount.html always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler is used as a default implementation class for AuthenticationSuccessHandler.

This should work as you expect.

I'm not sure what `authentication-success-handler-ref="ssoAuthenticationSuccessHandler"` is suppose to do, but try looking in to SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler and see if you can get any clue.

Comment: Can you also tell me when  authentication-success-handler-ref will be invoked?. Or Do I need to manually invoke?

Comment: actually, authentication-success-handler-ref will override the default AuthenticationSuccessHandler, so if you want to do some original handling for authentication-success, you will need to manually do it. ref ---> http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html